# Visual Studio Not Finding .dll At Runtime

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2013

I am writing a program in C# with Visual Studio 2013 that builds on another program I wrote. In development everything appears to be fine; I added a reference in my current program to the previous program and it picks up everything as expected. However, at runtime it throws a FileNotFound exception saying it can't find the program I am trying to build on top of even though the dll of the program I am trying to run and the program I am trying to reference are in the same directory and the reference is added properly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check your debugging directory? Try changing it to `$(TargetDir)`?

Comment: Maybe the platform is not cottect. I mean dll wrote for .net 4.5.1 and apllication is .net 4.0

Comment: Try to set "copy locally" for your dll in your project.

Comment: Both are targeting 4.5, setting the debugging directory to $(TargetDir) did nothing (assuming TargetDir is the location of the dlls) and copy locally is already set to true in my project for what I'm referencing

Comment: I'm writing an AutoCAD plugin if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the CPU type to any for all dlls involved